# Nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:
Solve the following first-order equation.

$(1+e^x)y'+e^y=0$

Comment: It is separable since you can move $y$ to one side and $x$ to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to be able to spot when a differential equation is **separable**.

Rewrite our equation as 
$$e^{-y}\,dy=-\frac{dx}{1+e^x},$$ 
and integrate. For the integral on the right, you may want to make the substitution $u=1+e^x$.

Comment: won't it be simpler to substitute $1+e^{-x}$ with u?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: It is **cleverer** to do as you suggest. But for someone not very experienced, the slower path $u=1+e^x$ is the more natural one.

Comment: @AndréNicolas There is a minus sign missing from your equation.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: Thank you for spotting it. Well, for spotting not it.

Answer (score 3):

So, $$\frac{dy}{e^y}=-\frac{dx}{e^x+1}$$

$$e^{-y}dy=\frac{-e^{-x}dx}{e^{-x}+1}$$

Integrating by putting $1+e^{-x}=z$ in the RHS,

$-e^{-y}=\ln(1+e^{-x})+C$

where $C$ is an arbitrary constant for indefinite integral.

Now, $\ln(1+e^{-x})=\ln\left(\frac{e^x+1}{e^x}\right)=\ln(e^x+1)-\ln e^x=\ln(e^x+1)-x$

Comment: There is a minus sign missing from your equation.

Comment: @AymanHourieh, thanks for your observation. rectified.

Answer (score 2):

This is a separable equation. Write it as:

$$
e^{-y}\, y' = -\frac{1}{1+e^x}
$$

Can you take it from here and integrate both sides?

Answer (score 2):

It's a separable equation.  It is first order, but certainly not linear ($e^y$ term...)

Note that we can make it:
$$(1+e^x)y' + e^y = 0$$
$$(1+e^x)y' = -e^y$$
$$\frac{(1+e^x)y'}{-e^y} = 1$$
$$-e^{-y}y' = \frac1{1+e^x}$$

Now, integrate both sides.  Let me know if you need further help.