# Linear first-order equation2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me to solve this question.

Question:

Solve the following first-order equation.

> $(1-x^2)y'=3(x^2)y$

Comment: There are many ways to solve that. Integrating factor is not the worst. You can also observe it is separable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know how to solve ode using [separation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables)?
Here you have:
$$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{3x^2}{1-x^2}dx$$

Answer (score 2):

This is a separable equation.  Please look at your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326695/nonlinear-differential-equation) and see if you can apply what you have learned there.

Hint: rewrite as:
$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{3x^2}{1-x^2}$$